# Does testflight wipeout local data?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, testflight

I have a react-native app that asks for user credentials if it detects that the device have no credentials previously saved, it didn't use to happen but nowadays whenever I update the app through test flight it asks for the credentials again.

Does testflight wipeout sqlite data?

I use react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

When using asyncStorage form react-native which also uses SQLite on Android, it doesn't wipe out the stored data, only if you delete the App.